# Cache just doesn't seem to work in clojure, what is the way to use it?

Tags: caching, clojure

I'm working on a simple project that shows some data that I'd like to see everyday. This will go on to my raspberry-pi. I'm using a free api that has a limit on requests so I thought I'd cache the requests so I don't spam the API. Here is what I've got so far:

```
(def KEY "Cache-Key")
(def CF (cache/ttl-cache-factory {} :ttl 43200)) ; 12 hour cache

(defn get-data-from-api
  [url]
  (let [response {:cache true :value 1}]
    (println "---> getting from http")
    response))

(defn get-data
  [url]
  (cache/lookup-or-miss CF KEY (get-data-from-api url)))
```

According to [this link](https://quanttype.net/posts/2020-10-25-caching-http-requests.html), this is all that is required. Except:

- my `get-data` function *always* gets it from the api (the `println` I added to debug gets printed always). The cache is being added just fine, just doesn't seem to fetch and return
- The `get-data` doesn't return anything. So when I do `curl http://localhost:3001/display` I get an empty response.

Am I using the cache correctly please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The last value to `lookup-or-miss` must be a function that will be called on a cache miss. In your code, you're first calling the function and then pass its result to the lookup function, so your function will be called unconditionally (after all, `lookup-or-miss` is a regular function itself and not a macro - it can't dictate when its arguments are evaluated).

Even in the article you link to, they pass `http-get` directly and the `url` serves as the key, which `lookup-or-miss` will use as an argument for `http-get` by default on a cache miss.

Comment: Hi thanks, you're right, I had misunderstood the premise of this. I thought my function had an arg so I was passing it as function-with-arg to cache, because my cache key is different to my function param. I just changed it now so that they're both the same and now it works. since this is a tiny hobby project it should be okay for now, thanks